# MSMQ security blocking traffic from RPC traffic in Windows Server 2003

Tags: security, msmq, rpc

I've created a Message Queue in a server running Windows Server 2003 and created a client program that is able to send messages, but I can't pull them back. To send messages, I am using the following code (note that I am using transactional queue):

```
    MessageQueueTransaction transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
    transaction.Begin();
    messageQueue.Send("Hello MSMQ!", "Title", transaction);
    transaction.Commit();
    transaction.Dispose();
```

To pull the messages I've tried this, without success:

```
    MessageQueueTransaction transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
    try
    {
        transaction.Begin();
        MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
        Message msg = queue.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), transaction);
        msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(String) });
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Label + " - " + msg.Body);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transaction.Abort();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

In the queue.Receive() call I am getting an exception. I've found a lot of similar questions about this, and I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx) with three possible solutions, but none of them worked for me. I disabled the firewall on the server, created the DWORD values in the registry, and one of the solutions provided seems to be specific for Windows Server 2008. Can anyone help me with remote calls from MSMQ in Windows Server 2003?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Are the *Distributed Transaction Coordinator* (DTC) services running on your machines?